# Unknown function 'apoc.date.format' in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

```
MATCH (s:Supplier)-[payment:Payment]->(m:Manufacturer)
MATCH (m)-[order:Order]->(s)
WHERE payment.approveddate <= (order.orderdate+1)
RETURN apoc.date.format(apoc.date.parse(payment.approveddate, 'ms', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'), 'ms', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
```

I am working on a project work, here s label for suppliers and m label for manufacturer. When i am executing this code, i am getting an error from the neo:

> Unknown function 'apoc.date.format' (line 4, column 8 (offset: 141))

My requirement is to print the list of date where payment label is holding the Approved dates of supplier and order label is holding the orderdate.

```
RETURN apoc.date.format
(apoc.date.parse(payment.approveddate, 'ms', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'), 
'ms', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
```

Here i would like to print when the payment.aproveddate is greater than or equal to order.orderdate + 1(date).

Comment: You'll want to make sure [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j.com/developer/neo4j-apoc/) is properly installed and configured to make use of the function. Can you confirm the versions of Neo4j and APOC you are using?

Answer (score 1):

More than likely APOC Procedures is not installed (or maybe not installed correctly).

As mentioned in my comment, you'll want to make sure APOC Procedures is properly installed and configured to make use of the function.